# iOS: How to partially change the color of text

Tags: ios

I was playing with iOS built-in Compass app and the UI do make me curious.

Here is the interesting part:

[image]

The color of text (even the circle) can be partially and dynamically changed.

I have made a lot of search, but the results are all about attributed string. How to implement the effect like this?

**Edited:**

I have tried to add two UILabels (`whiteLabel` and `blackLabel`) as `whitelabel` at the bottom and `blackLabel` at the top with the same frame. Then I set the circle as the mask of `blackLabel`.

The problem is 'whiteLabel' is totally covered by `blackLabel`, and if the circle do not intersect with 'blackLabel', both labels are not visible.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with an attributed string in my opinion. I expect that it's achived with the overlaying of UIViews of varying colors and transpancies.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that there are two "14" labels in the same place. The bottom one is white and unmasked, and the top one is black and has a layer mask that contains two circles, so it's only visible where the circles are.

Comment: That's actually possible too. And probably more efficient than my solution

Comment: Cool, I will try your solution

Answer (score 1):

Achieving this has most probably nothing to do with `NSAttributedStrings`, like Woodstock said.

I'd say it's the UILabel's layer that is recolored live, depending on what other layer it intersects with, and the overlaying area of said intersection.

Once you figure those common points, you just apply a mask that inverts colors from there.

Now it's a little bit more complicated than that since there appears to be two circles (hence two layers to find intersections with), but in the end, it's "just a list of coordinates" that the label's coordinates intersects or not.

That could be an interesting exercise ; it would probably take me a decent amount of tries to mimic that behaviour, but I'm pretty confident my reasoning is on point. (get it? :o)

Comment: Get it. I will turn to Apple's documents for more details about layer.